# Getting content of website to variable

Tags: ios, parsing, swift, web

I need to get a content of a website which is only a double value, nothing else to a variable.

I looked for a long time now and can't find any sollution how to do that.

Can anyone give me any tip where to begin with?

I'm very beginner in swift programming so please be understanding.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://yourUrl.com")
var error: NSError?
var string = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
if error == nil {
    var double = string?.doubleValue
}
```

Comment: Man thank you soooo soo much! That did the job! If i could i would give you +1! You rock!

Comment: That won't always work.  Have a look at this:         
var urlStr = "http://www.google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en-GB&source=hp&q=hello&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=1"
var urlEnc : String = urlStr.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var url2 = NSURL(string: urlEnc)
var error: NSError?
var string = NSString(contentsOfURL: url2!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
if error == nil {
    println("New Error = \(error)")
}